# How to receive props from a parent component when using getStaticProps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-props

Summary)
How do you receive props from a parent component when your current child component is receiving only the data as props from getStaticProps?

For example, Todos component is a child component of a parent component and Todos needs to receive props from the parent. Since I am using getStaticProps to fetch data in the beginning of the app, the Todos component has props from getStaticProps only.

```
const Todos = ({ todos }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {todos.length > 0 ? todos.map((todo) => <li>{todo}</li>) : "No todos"}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Todos;

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const todos = await fetch("https://.../todos");

  return {
    props: {
      todos,
    },
  };
}
```

1. In the parent component of Todos component:

```
export default function Home({ currentUser, setCurrentUser }) {
  return (
    <div>
     <Todos currentUser={currentUser} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser}/>
    </div>
  );
}

//and then in Todos.js

const Todos = ({ props }) => {
...}
```

If I pass in props like above, if I console log the props in Todos component, I only see 'currentUser'. I don't see the props (todos) from the getStaticProps.

2.So I tried another way using Link but I could not figure out a way to pass down props, currentUser and setCurrentUser using Link..

```
export default function Home({ currentUser, setCurrentUser }) {
  return (
    <div>
          <Link href="/Todos">
            <a>Click to see Todos</a>
          </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `getStaticProps` can only be used for page components (components in `/pages`) and only run on build time. If `currentUser` is needed for fetching todos and it is unknown in build time , `getStaticProps` is not the right solution to your problem.

Comment: @hangindev.com Yes Todos is a component in /pages folder. I wanted to display the data when the page is first loaded just as I would use useEffect() to fetch the initial data. I thought getStaticProps was the next.js version of useEffect(). Is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rule which states that you can only use server site functions like `getStaticProps()` or `getServerSideProps()` in a **page component** so I assume that you have **Home** as a page component and you want use **Todo Component** inside Home Component. In effect, you should transfer **getStaticProps()** to Home Component:

```
 export default function Home(props) {
  return (
   <div>
    <Todos todos={props.todos} currentUser={props.currentUser} setCurrentUser={props.setCurrentUser}/>
   </div>
   );
 }

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const todos = await fetch("https://.../todos");
  return {
    props: {
     todos,
    },
  };
}
```

In a nutshell; you should change your structure.